# Set variable while foreach loop is working

Tags: c#, foreach, label

I have foreach loop that copies files.
I want to set label to "Working.." while the foreach loop is copying the files.
I have tried:

```
label.text = "Ready";
foreach (file in files)
{
    File.Copy(firstDest, secondDest);
    label.text = "Working..";
}
label.text = "Ready";
```

But the label never changes even when it's copying the files for a while 2-3 seconds.
Do you know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: To verify your code, I would suggest you to use logging technique, You can just print `label.text` on `Console`, so you will get records of change in label text

Comment: It could be because `File.Copy` occupies the UI thread from start to finish so you won't see the label text refresh until the loop finishes. But by then the label is reset to the original text, so you won't see any changes.

Comment: Can you update with full UI code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do your copy operation in another thread.

```cs
 label.text = "Ready"; 
var tasks = Task[files.length];

for (var i=0 ; i<files.length; i++) { 
    tasks[i] = Task.Run(()=>{
        File.Copy(firstDest, secondDest); 
    });
}

label.text = "Working.."; 
await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
label.text = "Ready";
```

In case you want to run it all in one task and not each copy in parallel

```cs
label.text = "Ready"; 


var task =Task.Run(()=>{
foreach (file in files){
      File.Copy(firstDest, secondDest); 

}
});

label.text = "Working.."; 
await task;
label.text = "Ready";
```

Comment: `Task.WhenAll` returns another `Task` which completes when all of the tasks in `tasks` have completed. Because you never wait for this task, you will show "Ready" without waiting for any of the tasks to complete. You probably wanted an `await` in there.

Comment: Don't forget to make the function `async`, and `await` the call to `Task.WhenAll`.

Comment: Right , await added

Comment: You probably also don't want to run all of the copies in parallel - that isn't what the original question does, and it will only slow things down.

Comment: Good point , for that he can add the whole for loop in one task